# Class cast exception in map reduce job when writing data to MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop

I am trying a map reduce job to load data in the mysql data base, however I am facing a class cast exception error, here is the procedure I use:

I first creates a DBOutputWritable class that implements Writable and DBWritable interfaces.
I then use my reduce job to write the data in the data base, however when I run the job, it fails by saying that there was an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.amalwa.hadoop.DataBaseLoadMapReduce.DBOutputWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBWritable

at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBOutputFormat$DBRecordWriter.write(DBOutputFormat.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext.write(TaskInputOutputContext.java:80)
    at com.amalwa.hadoop.DataBaseLoadMapReduce.DBMapReduce$DBReducer.reduce(DBMapReduce.java:58)
    at com.amalwa.hadoop.DataBaseLoadMapReduce.DBMapReduce$DBReducer.reduce(DBMapReduce.java:53)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:663)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

I am having a hard time figuring out that if my class implements the interface that our required to write to a DB using a map reduce job, then why there is a class cast exception. I am implementing all the functions that are required.

Thanks.

```
DBOutputWritable
package com.amalwa.hadoop.DataBaseLoadMapReduce;

import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.db.DBWritable;


public class DBOutputWritable implements Writable, DBWritable{

 private String keyValue;
 private String response;

 public DBOutputWritable(String keyValue, String response){
 this.keyValue = keyValue;
 this.response = response; 
 }

 public void readFields(DataInput resultSet) throws IOException {

 }

 public void readFields(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
 keyValue = resultSet.getString(1);
 response = resultSet.getString(2);
 }

 public void write(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException {
 preparedStatement.setString(1, keyValue);
 preparedStatement.setString(2, response);
 }

 public void write(DataOutput dataOutput) throws IOException {

 }

}
```

Reducer:

```
public static class DBReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, DBOutputWritable, NullWritable>{

 public void reduce(Text requestKey, Iterable<Text> response, Context context){
 for(Text responseSet: response){
 try{
 context.write(new DBOutputWritable(requestKey.toString(), responseSet.toString()), NullWritable.get());
 }catch(IOException e){
 System.err.println(e.getMessage());
 }
 catch(InterruptedException e){
 System.err.println(e.getMessage());
 }
 }
 }
 }
```

Mapper:

public static class DBMapper extends Mapper{

```
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException{
        String tweetInfo = value.toString();
        String[] myTweetData = tweetInfo.split(",", 2);
        String requestKey = myTweetData[0];
        String response = myTweetData[1];
        try {
            context.write(new Text(requestKey), new Text(response));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());;
        }
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        DBConfiguration.configureDB(conf, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://ec2-54-152-254-194.compute-1.amazonaws.com/TWEETS", "user", "password");
        Job job = new Job(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(DBMapReduce.class);
        job.setMapperClass(DBMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(DBReducer.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(DBOutputWritable.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(DBOutputFormat.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        DBOutputFormat.setOutput(job, "TWEET_INFO", new String[] { "REQUESTKEY", "TWEET_DETAILS" });
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are mixing the old (`org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*`) and new (`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*`) MapReduce APIs, and it is causing a conflict. My suspicion is your `DBReducer` class is extending the `Reducer` class from the new API but your `DBOutputWritable` is implementing `DBWritable` from the old API.

You should choose only one of those APIs across your implementation, which means that all imported MapReduce types begin with the same package prefix.

Note that typically you implement MapReduce interfaces when using the old API, and extend MapReduce base classes when using the new API.